# Extra packages in setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I created a package which has 2 modes:

- the basic mode with basic functionality only
- extended functionality which adds additional modules and needs extra requirements.

For example:

- MyPackageName

  - core
  - cyber_analyzer
  - parsing

Where "parsing" is the extension and needs "pandas" as requirement.

Then, I want my package to have 2 modes:

- `pip install mypackage`
- `pip install mypackage[parsing]`

I found out I can use `extras_require` to install "pandas". Yet, installing the `whl` file would install all the 3 modules: core, cyber_analyzer and parsing. I would like to install "parsing" only if the extra flag "parsing" was specified.

Is it possible to do so? How can I achieve it? Should I always install "parsing" and the users shouldn't use it?

Comment: "*Is it possible to do so?*" Not with a single wheel. You can split the source into 3 packages. "*Should I always install "parsing" and the users shouldn't use it?*" It's the simplest solution.